# Groovy error with method mod or %

Tags: groovy, sequence

I just started to program in Groovy, I have got this error and I wanted to see if anyone could help me to work it out.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot use mod() on this number type: java.math.BigDecimal with value: 5
    at Script1.hailstone(Script1.groovy:8)
    at Script1$hailstone.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at Script1.hailstone(Script1.groovy:11)
    at Script1$hailstone.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at Script1.hailstone(Script1.groovy:14)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:1)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
```

I have the following Groovy code

```
def list = [1,2,3].findAll{it-> hailstone(it)}

def hailstone(num){
    if(num==1){
        return 1;
    }
    println num
    println num.mod(2)
    if(num.mod(2)==0){
        num = num/2;
        return 1 + hailstone(num)
    }else{
        num = 3*num + 1
        return 1 + hailstone(num)
    }
}
```

​
​

and the output:

```
2
0
3
1 
10
0
5
```

and then it suddenly throws an error on 5.mod(2).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like 'num' is getting coerced into a BigDecimal when you hit the line 
`num = num/2`

If you change the signature of the hailstone method to:
`def hailstone(int num)` it will not crash (because the parameter will get coerced to an int on each invocation), but this may not give the results that you want, as you will lose precision, e.g. when 'num' is an odd number, and num/2 yields a decimal value, the value will be truncated.

For more info on the (sometimes surprising) way that Groovy math operations work, take a look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math

Answer (score 0):

After running this code, it was not producing the right output because of the findAll. Here is the code with some minor tweaks:

```
def list = [1,2,3].collect { hailstone(it) }  // use collect, no need for the "it ->" variable it is implicit.

 def hailstone(int num) {      // int data type to prevent BigDecimal from being passed to mod()
   if (num == 1) {
     return 1                  // no need for semi-colons in groovy
   } else if (num % 2 == 0) {  // use modulus operator 
     num = num / 2
   } else {
     num = 3 * num + 1
   }

   return 1 + hailstone(num)   // this line happens regardless of the condition in the else if or the else
 }

 println list  // outputs : [1,2,8]
```